# I am getting duplicate data on table while selecting values from multiple select box

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using html select2 jQuery select box..on selecting  any value my table gets relevant information about the value i selected

If  there are values like one , two ,three on select box...

When i select one , i gets the information about option one in html table below

When i select two also..  now i am getting  values from one  plus one again and two.which is quite obvious ..

I am appending to the table using jQuery each function..

I know also clearing the table first will solve my problem but the thing is  in table i have a check box control as well which i select.... If i clear the table i loose the checked check box

New values gets appended to the table after clearing the table first ..

Now the problem is i want no dublicate values for like one.  And when i select two . I will get
Results of 1 and 1 and 2 appended...

Second i want the checkbox to retain the checked state which i made previous..

Hope i made my question understandable... Please help me

I am stuck...

Thanks in advance ..

Have a good day...

Comment: What exact data you are getting in ajax success ?

Comment: You can check inside each that if element exists with some id or class then do not append

Comment: @GhanshyamSingh  you mean inside success amd store the value first then compare values against new bindings

Comment: Yes, Can you paste the HTML which is retuning from ajax call

Comment: @GhanshyamSingh yes sure...i will

Comment: @GhanshyamSingh  please see the ajax success function

  success: function (data) {
               // $('#tblItemsBody').empty();
                $.each(data, function (i, obj) {
                    $('#tblItemsBody').append($("<tr>  <td>  <input type='checkbox' class='chk' id=" + obj.Item_Id + "> <label for=" + obj.Item_Id + " class='p-0'></label> </td>  <td> " + obj.SalesOrderId + "  </td>  <td>  " + obj.Item_Code + "</td>  <td> " + obj.AEGG_Description + " </td>  <td>  " + obj.Manufacturer + "</td>  <td>" + obj.OEM_Reference + " </td>   </tr>"))

                });

Answer (score 1):

**You just need to check if a row already exists by:-**

> 1. Add dynamic id to each row  like `id='row_"+obj.Item_Id+"'` i have added.
> 2. Check if the row exists by checking the length `$("#tblItemsBody tr#row_"+obj.Item_Id).length ==0`

**Code:-**

```
$.ajax({
      ...options,
      success: function(data) { 
      $.each(data, function (i, obj) 
             {
               if($("#tblItemsBody tr#row_"+obj.Item_Id).length ==0 ){
                 $('#tblItemsBody').append("<tr id='row_"+obj.Item_Id+"'> <td> <input type='checkbox' class='chk' id=" + obj.Item_Id + "> "+
                 <label for=" + obj.Item_Id + " class='p-0'></label> </td> <td> " + obj.SalesOrderId + " </td> <td> " + obj.Item_Code + "</td> <td> " 
                + obj.AEGG_Description + " </td> <td> " + obj.Manufacturer + "</td> <td>" + obj.OEM_Reference + " </td> </tr>")) 
               }

             });
    })
```